# Android app crashes when I press the "Ask question" button

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

Perhaps this was already captured by your auto-logging.  To reproduce the crash on my phone:

1. Open the app
2. Open navigation drawer on the left, select a site (e.g. Stack Overflow)
3. Press the "Ask Question" icon in the top-right.

Perhaps relevant, I have only posted answers on Stack Overflow. If this is meant to show me a summary of my questions, it will have nothing to show.  [Edit:  This also occurs if I'm looking at this site "Meta", where I have at least one question  :-)  ]

My Android version is 4.0.4.

To expand on a comment, "crash" in this context means:

1. App freezes, unresponsive, same graphics
2. App presents a black screen.  OS status bar remains on the top.
3. Home and power button have no effect at this point
4. Idle time causes phone to turn off.
5. Power button turns phone on, but screen cannot be unlocked.
6. Some time later, phone can be unlocked, presenting:
7. Notification the "TouchWiz home is not responding.  Would you like to close it" (OK)
8. Notification: "Unfortunately, StackExchange has stopped" (OK)
9. Dropped into last open app
10. Home button now works.  There is a delay where it appears that the app list is repopulating.
11. Now phone appears to be back.

Comment: Having never used the app, I am only guessing... But by "crash" do you mean "exit", and by "the Q button" do you mean "the quit button"? In which case, this may be the expected behavior :-)

Comment: Good thought, but unlikely.  "Crash" means screen is black except for a thin bar at the top. Phone is unresponsive.  User is left frustrated and mashing any available button (especially home and power) until something happens.  The second time I managed to get the app launcher to restart.  The Q button is the icon SO uses to represent a question.  For example it is prominate on a site that you do not have an account in.

Comment: Wow that's a nasty crash, reminds me of IE6 causing the whole computer to freeze... more than a few times.

Answer (score 2):

After the update on 8/28/2013 this is fixed.